# Get Property Value of Nested Classes Where Field or Property Names are not Known at Run Time

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

I am building a property search solution which would allow the user to lookup each property name and value in a list of nested properties where the names are not known in advance. The only class object known at run time is the parent class. In the below example I am passing the parent object (atype) to a method which returns (desired) a dictionary of all parent and child member keys and values.

Assumption: Each parent class has multiple nested classes. In the below the Parent is aType. It is child's play to retrieve the parent level properties with simple types, but not the nested class properties when the property names of the nested class properties are not known at run time.

The only solution I have found is a property lookup option where the full class path is known at run time. This is not an option when the class contains multiple classes of unknown properties. Some of the nested classes contain other class properties with their own set of fields and properties. Thus, no assumption may be made about class depth.

Desired: Provide an option for searching the parent and all nested classes without previous knowledge of the nested class(s) property names.

```
public static Dictionary<string, object> DictionaryFromType(object atype)
    {
        if (atype == null) return new Dictionary<string, object>();
        var t = atype.GetType();
        var props = t.GetProperties();
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (var prp in props)
        {
            if (prp.PropertyType.IsClass)
            {
                 // The property Names of the Nested Class are not known at 
                 // this point. This is an example.
                 // At this point I only know the property is a class. 
                 // Passing the property class name yields no result.
                    var nestedValue = GetPropertyValue(atype, "childClass.nameField");
                    if (nestedValue != null)
                    dict.Add(prp.Name, nestedValue);
            }

            var value = GetPropertyValue(atype, prp.Name);
            if (value != null)
            dict.Add(prp.Name, value);
        }
        return dict;
    }
```

The below works perfectly well when the appropriate object and nesting are provided. It makes no attempt to lookup a nested object where only the object name is provided.

```
public static object GetPropertyValue(object obj, string propertyName)
    {
        var propertyNames = propertyName.Split('.');

        foreach (string t in propertyNames)
        {
            if (obj != null)
            {
                var propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(t);
                if (propertyInfo != null)
                    obj = propertyInfo.GetValue(obj);
                else
                    obj = null;
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

Below is a modified version of my DictionaryFromType Method. I used Heath's Child Property lookup Method to obtain the Second Level. This works perfectly at the second level. Still desired - an option to recursively search through potential child classes found in each Child.

```
public static Dictionary<string, object> DictionaryFromType(object atype)
    {
        if (atype == null) return new Dictionary<string, object>();
        var t = atype.GetType();
        var props = t.GetProperties();
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        try
        {

        foreach (var prp in props)
        {
            if (prp.PropertyType.IsClass)
            {
                // The property Names of the Nested Class are not known at this point
                var nestedValue = GetNestedPropertyValue(atype, prp.Name);
                if (nestedValue == null) continue;
                var childType = nestedValue.GetType();
                // Loop through the first Sub Class of child properties
                // If this level is a Class, no properties will be returned.
                // Still Needed: A way to loop through Children of Children to see if the the Property is a Class
                foreach (var property in childType.GetProperties())
                {
                    var childTypePropertyValue = GetPropertyValue(atype, prp.Name + "." + property.Name);
                    if (!dict.ContainsKey(property.Name) && !dict.ContainsValue(childTypePropertyValue))
                    {
                        dict.Add(property.Name, childTypePropertyValue);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                    var value = GetPropertyValue(atype, prp.Name);
                    if (value != null)
                        if (!dict.ContainsKey(prp.Name) && !dict.ContainsValue(value))
                        {
                            dict.Add(prp.Name, value);
                        }
                }
        }
        return dict;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("Error Building Dictionary : " + ex.Message);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, you can just retrieve the value of the property `var value = GetPropertyValue(atype, prp.Name);`, then recursively call your method with that value (`DictionaryFromType(value)`) and finally merge the result dictionary into the parent

Answer (score 0):

You got that the property type was a class (which, honestly, almost everything in .NET would be, including `String`) but you first need to reflect that type and enumerate its properties, like (basic example; makes some assumptions and elides error handling for brevity):

```cs
static object GetPropertyValue(object parent, string nestedPropertyName)
{
    object propertyValue = null;

    var tokens = nestedPropertyName.Split('.');
    foreach (var token in tokens)
    {
      var property = parent.GetType().GetProperty(token, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
      propertyValue = property.GetValue(parent);

      if (propertyValue is null) return null;
      parent = propertyValue;
    }

    return propertyValue;
}
```

Comment: Where I'm getting jammed up is that the property name is the class name without the dot notation, because I don't have a collection of the nested properties. That takes me back to the original issue of getting the list of property names with the dot notation so I can recall the lookup, elg.   var nestedValue = GetPropertyValue(atype, prp.Name); When the lookup is a class it simply looks like [className] in prp.Name. Therefore using the split option does nothing to supply the underlying property names.

Comment: So you want the first part of nestedPropertyName to actually be the property type? What if multiple properties are of that type, which would happen most often (e.g. multiple string properties, as strings are a common property type). Even still, if you know the structure of nestedPropertyName, then check the first token against the property.PropertyType.Name in my sample and the second token is the property name from which you get the value.

Comment: Heath - I borrowed your GetPropertyValue method and with a few changes to my Create Dictionary Method, I was able to glean the child object name from the parent class and then use the fully qualified propertyName of the child to complete the lookup against the parent atype. That works great at level 2. It would be great to have a more elegant recursion option for getting down to levels 2 + n. No repeating the same code to dig into the next level. You mentioned early that every type is potentially a class, true, but there is obvious distinction when you pose the "has a" question to a class.

Comment: You don't need recursion. My solution supports deeply nested properties. Please give it a try with a class with deep properties and consider marking it as the answer if it helped you.

Comment: I have fed the above with a deeply nested set of properties and it stops at level 2. Unless there is a way to devise the full path of the nested class structure, it will simply see the class name and return nothing. Your solution works only when the fully defined nested path is sent as the argument. The issue this then how to retrieve the full path of the class without knowing how deep the structure is. I would consider this a partial solution to the issue.